# Type-ahead drop down with ajax database lookup and comma-separated values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'd like a user to be able to type comma-separated aircode codes into a asp.net webform (VB.NET) text box like this:

Airport Codes: **JFK,LAX,LHR**

and as the user is typing, a type-ahead drop-down list drops down to have up 5 options like this:

User types "L", the following drops down:

```
LOO - Laghouat Airport (Algeria) 
LAD - Luanda De Fevereiro Airport (Angola) 
LBZ - Lucapa Airport (Angola) 
LUO - Luena Airport (Angola) 
LPG - La Plata Airport (Argentina)
```

then

User types "LA", the following drops down:

```
LAA - Lamar Muni Airport (United States)
LAC - Layang Layang Airport (Malaysia)
LAD - Luanda De Fevereiro Airport (Angola)
LAE - Nadzab Airport (Papua New Guinea)
LAF - Purude University Airport (United States)
```

then

User types "LAX", the following drops down:

```
LAX - Los Angeles Intl Airport (United States)
LLA - Kallax Airport (Sweden)
TXA - Tlaxcala Airport (Mexico)
```

(Notice the 'lax' text in the airport names rather than the airport codes after Los Angeles Intl Airport sicnce there are no other codes contain LAX and the drop-down list wasn't yet 5 items long.)

Then if the user types a comma, the drop down begins again for a new code.

Here's a MS SQL table for the airport codes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes](
    [CounterID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AirportName] [nvarchar](70) NOT NULL,
    [CityName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [IATAFAA] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
    [ICAO] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
    [Latitude] [numeric](19, 15) NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] [numeric](19, 15) NOT NULL,
    [Altitude] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Timezone] [nvarchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [DST] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [TzDatabaseTimeZone] [nvarchar](22) NULL,
    [IDKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblVReferenceAirportCodes_IDKey]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblVReferenceAirportCodes_CreatedDateTime]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [ReferenceCityCounterID] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblVReferenceAirportCodes_ReferenceCityCounterID]  DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And some items:

```
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8825, N'Bamyan Airport', N'Bamyan', N'Afghanistan', N'BIN', N'OABN', CAST(34.816667000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(67.816667000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'2550', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'510ce7d9-5ae9-452a-ad7c-1bf96ffcba62', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (7868, N'Camp Bastion', N'Camp Bastion', N'Afghanistan', N'-', N'OAZI', CAST(31.865556000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(64.195278000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'2808', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'0e026714-acf9-4552-9c70-0e32f31b2635', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 151)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (7501, N'Chaghcharan Airport', N'Chaghcharan', N'Afghanistan', N'CCN', N'OACC', CAST(34.526667000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(65.271667000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'7383', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'04c87be0-172e-4278-9455-31f735ffa14e', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (5922, N'Faizabad Airport', N'Faizabad', N'Afghanistan', N'FBD', N'OAFZ', CAST(37.121100000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(70.518100000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3872', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'd737462a-d6fe-42ea-a9c1-c4586fe489bd', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2048, N'Herat', N'Herat', N'Afghanistan', N'HEA', N'OAHR', CAST(34.210017000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(62.228300000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3206', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'c5b5a9f7-c2de-4a34-8b2b-263a26a11244', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2049, N'Jalalabad', N'Jalalabad', N'Afghanistan', N'JAA', N'OAJL', CAST(34.399842000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(70.498625000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'1814', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'98a5ea59-bb8d-4a6f-8478-46f960f07b9c', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (7036, N'Bagram AFB', N'Kabul', N'Afghanistan', N'BPM', N'OAIX', CAST(34.564600000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(69.155400000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'4895', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'f920cdc0-1b59-4f77-a76f-40dc470bd467', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2050, N'Kabul Intl', N'Kabul', N'Afghanistan', N'KBL', N'OAKB', CAST(34.565853000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(69.212328000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'5877', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'a434a144-f619-48d7-9ddf-cef26c0d0417', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2051, N'Kandahar', N'Kandahar', N'Afghanistan', N'KDH', N'OAKN', CAST(31.505756000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(65.847822000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3337', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'4bf12014-c579-4ba1-b160-20f290ebede6', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8127, N'FOB Salerno', N'Khost', N'Afghanistan', N'KHT', N'OAKS', CAST(33.333400000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(69.952000000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3756', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'a5a5c26a-abc2-4f6d-898a-e366df986116', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2056, N'Konduz', N'Kunduz', N'Afghanistan', N'UND', N'OAUZ', CAST(36.665111000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(68.910833000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'1457', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'a4c48394-289d-493a-a0e8-a8ca84c5ecf2', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8773, N'Bost Airport', N'Lashkar Gah', N'Afghanistan', N'BST', N'OABT', CAST(31.558889000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(64.364167000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'2464', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'2b150472-90d7-42e3-82d4-7db7eda3bec1', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 179)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2052, N'Maimana', N'Maimama', N'Afghanistan', N'MMZ', N'OAMN', CAST(35.930789000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(64.760917000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'2743', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'1b368ecf-64ab-4412-bb86-32d8670025ce', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2053, N'Mazar I Sharif', N'Mazar-i-sharif', N'Afghanistan', N'MZR', N'OAMS', CAST(36.706914000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(67.209678000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'1284', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'1ddc8b0a-0a87-45cf-9ed8-6fe7a2c9abf2', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8267, N'FOB Shank', N'Shank', N'Afghanistan', N'-', N'OASH', CAST(33.921369000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(69.078130000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'6614', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'827c23fa-5ff6-4090-a124-f0207e9b4d46', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8145, N'FOB Sharana', N'Sharan', N'Afghanistan', N'-', N'-', CAST(33.127772150000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(68.836984700000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'7400', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'7450f6d6-88e4-49e5-b5ca-ddf281ff895f', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (8146, N'Sharona', N'Sharona', N'Afghanistan', N'AZ3', N'OASA', CAST(33.127721500000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(68.836984700000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'7400', N'4.5', N'N', N'Asia/Kabul', N'207e120a-0e31-4c8b-9327-4c5ddf9b7f9a', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 192)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2055, N'Sheberghan', N'Sheberghan', N'Afghanistan', N'-', N'OASG', CAST(36.750783000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(65.913164000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'1053', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'31d8e74f-0805-4918-af6f-81ac7b48223e', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (2054, N'Shindand', N'Shindand', N'Afghanistan', N'-', N'OASD', CAST(33.391331000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(62.260975000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3773', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'b8f42640-c787-4e1f-af03-5cd8002a3ede', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 195)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (7499, N'Tarin Kowt Airport', N'Tarin Kowt', N'Afghanistan', N'TII', N'OATN', CAST(32.605278000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(65.864167000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'3500', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'b0fcd4fd-616d-4bb4-9b16-4b486bc1a112', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 198)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (7500, N'Zaranj Airport', N'Zaranj', N'Afghanistan', N'ZAJ', N'OAZJ', CAST(30.969167000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(61.866944000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'1581', N'4.5', N'U', N'Asia/Kabul', N'05c3e3e4-e0ed-4977-ac41-dfb066f2ad53', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (1190, N'Tirana Rinas', N'Tirana', N'Albania', N'TIA', N'LATI', CAST(41.414742000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(19.720561000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'126', N'1', N'E', N'Europe/Tirane', N'1d765120-b8c9-4e65-9b0c-599a1ae6a612', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tblVReferenceAirportCodes] ([CounterID], [AirportName], [CityName], [Country], [IATAFAA], [ICAO], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Altitude], [Timezone], [DST], [TzDatabaseTimeZone], [IDKey], [CreatedDateTime], [ReferenceCityCounterID]) VALUES (234, N'Touat Cheikh Sidi Mohamed Belkebir', N'Adrar', N'Algeria', N'AZR', N'DAUA', CAST(27.837589000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), CAST(-0.186414000000000 AS Numeric(19, 15)), N'919', N'1', N'N', N'Africa/Algiers', N'6a56527a-55e2-4abc-a08c-43e967387ff1', CAST(0x0000A4F20054060C AS DateTime), 22383)
```

Note that the comma-separated list could contain a combination of either ICAO (normally 3-digit) or IATAFAA (normally 4-digit) codes. Some airports don't have an IATAFAA code while others don't have a ICAO code.

Question:

Does anyone have/know of a type-ahead drop down that does ajax database lookups but also allows for comma-separated values?

TIA
Mark

Comment: The [kendo autocomplete](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index) does that.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote ?